# How to get the ID of a editing textbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to get the ID of a textbox like below to add validator, the Client ID contains generated string, UniqueID too, but only the ID contains nothing, why?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    'Manipulate only editing row.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If sender.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then

            'Search textbox and add validators.
            For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells                
                If cell.Controls.Count = 1 AndAlso TypeOf (cell.Controls(0)) Is TextBox Then
                    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(cell.Controls(0), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)

                    'txt.ID is nothing...why?
                    SetValidators(cell.Controls, txt.ID)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why you do that in code behind? You can do this stuff in form view.\

Comment: There are about 20 target tables to edit, so I want to generate automatically.

Comment: Are you sure you execute code in update mode? Are you sure you assigned ID to TextBox??

Comment: No, I'm not assigning ID to TextBoxes. because the GridView generate them automatically.

Comment: So add validator in textbox generation block.

Comment: Where is that?... I can't get the ID in 'GridView1.RowCreated' neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'v solved that problem by to apply the workaround below.

```
            Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(cell.Controls(0), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)

            'The ID is generated by to refer ClientID.
            Dim foo = txt.ClientID

            'Therefore, already txt.ID is not nothing.
            SetValidators(cell.Controls, txt.ID)
```

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a workaround if applies to your application ,

```
Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(cell.Controls(0), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)

                //'txt.ID is nothing...why?
                 // Here you can assign new ID to your control as per your logic

                    txt.ID = "newID"; 
                   SetValidators(cell.Controls, txt.ID)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I already tried this workaround, and all columns are updated as null if applies...

Comment: @JumpeiTanaka You mean you are assigning `RequiredFieldValidators` it's not working.

Comment: No, I mean inputted values are disappear and they are updated as null.

Comment: @JumpeiTanaka Ok ! Yes it will cause assigning new id' and you may be doing updates  with old values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code to assign the validator control to the gridview control.
I am not sure what your doing with `SetValidators()`function.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    'Manipulate only editing row.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If sender.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then

            'Search textbox and add validators.
            For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells                
                If cell.Controls.Count = 1 AndAlso TypeOf (cell.Controls(0)) Is TextBox Then
                    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(cell.Controls(0), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)

                    'txt.ID is nothing...why?
                    SetValidators(cell.Controls, txt.ClientID)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's too long to show, but just only adding validators. I want to set txt.ID to `RegularExpressionValidator.ControlToValidate`.

Comment: After apply above, this exception occured. Control ID 'gvMainte_ctl02_6' that is referenced in the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'VldtBytesgvMainte_ctl02_6' can not be found.